# GLFW causes memory leak?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

Recently, I've discovered valgrind, and I've been using it to detect memory leaks. I have also been trying to start a project making use of a window handling library, preferably compatible with OpenGL. To my surprise, even creating a simple window using GLFW3 causes a memory leak (according to valgrind). Is this an issue with GLFW3?
(BTW, my setup):

```
OS: Arch Linux griffin 5.13.7-arch1-1
GPU: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (Driver nvidia, version: 470.57.02)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F 2.90GHz
```

GLFW3:(Code)

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    glfwInit();
    auto window = glfwCreateWindow(640,480,"Title",0,0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

(Producing Executable)

```
g++ -O0 -g -o run main.cpp -lglfw -lGLEW
```

(valgrind)

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=out.txt ./run
```

(valgrind output)

```
==3294== 116,211 (896 direct, 115,315 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 447 of 447
==3294==    at 0x484383F: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1192)
==3294==    by 0x72F0162: ??? (in /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x72E66D0: ??? (in /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x72E3D3E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x72F5DC1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x5D7CC78: ??? (in /usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x5DE2C55: ??? (in /usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x5D7C1E2: ??? (in /usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.470.57.02)
==3294==    by 0x4D0DEFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==3294==    by 0x400FDE8: call_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so)
==3294==    by 0x400FF1B: _dl_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so)
==3294==    by 0x4E36D44: _dl_catch_exception (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==3294==
==3294== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3294==    definitely lost: 7,176 bytes in 4 blocks
==3294==    indirectly lost: 135,760 bytes in 751 blocks
==3294==      possibly lost: 896 bytes in 1 blocks
==3294==    still reachable: 62,569 bytes in 847 blocks
==3294==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3294==
==3294== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3294== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: asking for libraries is offtopic. You should reword the question. I think no window library causes leaks when used correctly.

Comment: focus on the issue and ask how to fix it. I am almost certain that your premise "all those libraries cause leaks" is only based on using them wrong. But then you'd need to focus on one issue and include a [mcve]. For example "I won't post the code, since I've already deleted it" isnt something we can help with

Comment: you could remove all but the sfml code from the question and ask why a leak is reported and how to fix it

Comment: Video drivers have been known to leak memory. Use Valgrind suppressions to ignore leaks caused by your driver.

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak is not in GLFW, but in the video driver. See the paths that Valgrind lists. There's not much you can or need to do about this.
These kind of leaks can be suppressed in Valgrind, if necessary.

In my experience (on Manjaro), both the Nvidia and nouveau drivers have this leak, but the AMD drivers do not. As an experiment, you may want to run your program on an AMD GPU or the integrated Intel GPU. Chances are that the identical program will not have any leaks there.